# Pytorch module not found in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytorch

For the life of me I can't get the VSCode integrated terminal to correctly run a simple program that just has `import torch` in it. I've tried it all. I tried just installing pytorch via conda (I have Anaconda) inside the VSCode terminal, and then running my program inside the VSCode terminal as well. I tried creating a conda virtual environment, activating it, installing pytorch in it, and then running my program using the virtual environment. I tried switching the VSCode python to `('base': conda)` and it didn't work. I tried switching the VSCode python to `('pytorch': conda)` (I read this somewhere on StackOverflow), but I didn't find this. I tried uninstalling and re-installing the Python extension in VSCode. I tried just running `python3` inside the VSCode terminal and seeing if `>>> import torch` would run, but it doesn't. I tried installing `torch` with `pip` or `pip3` instead of with `conda` but it doesn't work, it just tells me that `No matching distribution found for torch`.

However, outside of VSCode, I can do `import torch` and it runs correctly. How could I solve this? I would very much prefer to use VSCode and its integrated terminal, but VSCode can't find pytorch for the life of me.

EDIT: Using MacOS Monterey and most updated python extension in VSCode

Comment: It is likely that the terminal run in your VS Code doesn't recognize the conda environment. Are you using Windows? First, check what is the terminal used in your integrated terminal inside VS Code. Second, check what is the terminal you used outside VS Code. If they don't match, try to change the inside one to be the same as the outside one. I guess that would help you solve the problem. You can let us know what are they as well.

Comment: No, I'm on mac. How do I check "the terminal used"? I thought the terminal is just the window. How can I check if "the terminals match"? I don't really understand what this means or how to "change the inside terminal"

Comment: What about typing `conda activate pytorch` after you run the integrated terminal inside VS Code? The virtual environment indicated on the status bar is meant for running a script not for the integrated terminal.

Comment: Yeah I was doing that immediately after creating my `pytorch_env` environment. Not working.

What do you mean by your last sentence? What is the difference between running a script and running something inside the integrated terminal?

Comment: @Watchanan, running `echo $SHELL` on both my usual terminal and the VSCode terminal prints `/bin/zsh`, if that's what you mean by "checking that the terminals match"